# Sort a string in typescript by specific characters after splitting?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Sorry if the question was a bit unclear, but I have a string I'm trying to sort. The string looks something like this:

```
1=10431,4=3,24=0,5=1-0,6=1-0,3=7.0,98=0,40=14,42=20210406080000,345=2021-03-29 12:15:11,51=1247,52=57,53=130,...
```

Right now, let's call that string "data". I use this:

```
        <DataContainer>
          {data.split(",")?.map((data, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>{data}</div>;
          })}
        </DataContainer>
```

to get it into a format that I can display. However, I also want to sort the data by the numbers that occur before the "=" sign. I'm a bit confused on how I could do that as I am already splitting the data commas.

Comment: If `data` is always a string (even if an empty one), then `data.split(",")` will always be an array, no need to use the `?.` operator before `.map()`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it into an object, then iterate over the object's values (which will be in ascending numeric key order):

```
{
  Object.values(
    Object.fromEntries(
      data.split(',').map(str => [str.split('=')[0], str])
    )
  )
    .map((str, i) => <div key={i}>{str}</div>)
}
```

A less funky looking solution would be to use an array, and sort it. To avoid splitting every time the sorting process occurs (`O(n log n)`), you can make the array contain objects instead of strings.

```
{
  data
    .split(',')
    .map(
      str => ({ num: str.split('=')[0], str })
    )
    .sort((a, b) => a.num - b.num);
    .map(({ str }, i) => <div key={i}>{str}</div>)
}
```

Comment: With your first call of data.map in your second solution, that will work on a plain string?

Comment: On that note, the first answer works off the bat and makes sense to me, if turning a string to an object and iterating over it automatically "sorts" it, or rather iterates over in ascending order, if I'm understanding correctly. The datasets aren't that big so I don't think the complexity is a big issue, but I'll see if I can get your second answer to working. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, that's right, when iterating over an object, keys that are array indicies will always be iterated over in ascending order. It's a clever (maybe too clever) way of automatically sorting.